# Creating a search input field having an internal icon, using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying to learn Tailwind CSS and generally working better with CSS. In this case, I am trying to make my search icon appear inside of my search input field.

I found some tutorials online but they mostly use plain CSS.

Is there any simple way to achieve this using Tailwind?

```
import React from "react";
import { FaSearch } from "react-icons/fa";

const SearchBar = () => {
  return (
<div>
   <input className="bg-slate-50 hover:bg-red-200 rounded-3xl h-12 w-56" />
   <FaSearch />
</div>
```

[image]

I also tried to wrap the input elment in a `<div>` and `<form>` tags, but none of those worked.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```html
<div className='flex items-center'>
  <input className='bg-slate-50 hover:bg-red-200 rounded-3xl h-12 w-56' />
  <SearchIcon className='-ml-9' />
</div>
```

Docs:

- [align items](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-items) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)
- [using negative margins](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/margin#using-negative-values) | [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)

Comment: Thank you, it worked, can you please explain what is the "-ml-9" means ?

I understand it's margin left - the  "-" is throwing me off a bit,
Thanks again!!

Comment: @Adrob, added links. It's negative margin. All margins in tailwind have a negative version, if you prefix the `m` with `-`. `-ml-9` means `margin-left: -36px;` You can use `-ml-10` or `-ml-8` instead, obviously.